# Bash history handling with multiple terminals

Tags: command-line, bash, history

I use mainly Terminator, and it's usually opened with 3 split terminal windows. I also use Gnome terminal for various reasons.
I'm wondering how is bash history handled in this case as I sometimes miss previously issued commands when I run `history`

For example, my prompt shows current bash history line (`\!`) and if I launch Terminator with 3 split terminal windows I get same history line (let's say 100) on all terminals. Which history will be saved?

Also launching Gnome Terminal after using Terminator I get line 100 at startup regardless all commands issued before in Terminator

Comment: Related on Unix SE: [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1288/154671)

Comment: Also consider this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834786

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The bash session that is saved is the one for the terminal that is closed the latest. If you want to save the commands for every session, you could use the trick explained [here](http://northernmost.org/blog/flush-bash_history-after-each-command/).

> ```
> export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
> ```
>
> To quote the manpage: “If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.”
>
> So every time my command has finished, it appends the unwritten history item to `~/.bash_history` before displaying the prompt (only $PS1) again.
>
> So after putting that line in `/etc/bash.bashrc` I don’t have to find myself reinventing wheels or lose valuable seconds re-typing stuff just because I was lazy with my terminals.

Anyway, you'll need to take into account that commands from different sessions will be mixed in your history file so it won't be so straightforward to read it later.

See also:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows

Comment: isn't it stored separately for different TTL??

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for explanation and solution. I tried with `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -r'` and I got some strange history line numbers in terminal - after issuing some command history line number jumps by 2000 instead by 1, which is strange but it behaves as said - all terminals history is saved.

Comment: @VineetMenon For more details look [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_106.html). Interesting parts: When the shell starts up, the history is initialized from the file named by the HISTFILE variable (default `~/.bash_history'). [...] When an interactive shell exits, the last $HISTSIZE lines are copied from the history list to the file named by $HISTFILE.

Comment: This website seems down: https://northernmost.org/blog/flush-bash_history-after-each-command/

Comment: [`export` is not needed.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107851/154671)

Comment: "won't be so straightforward to read it later." How do you work? I usually work on one terminal at a time following a thread of thought ;-) The history shouldn't be much worse than your train of thought...

Comment: I tested this and found that after setting PROMPT_COMMAND the commands that appear when running "history" are not updated immediately in memory for each open terminal, but rather when you open a new terminal. This matches the explanation in jcollado's comment.

Answer (score 44):

After multiple readings of `man bash`, I use separate history files for each shell. I did a `mkdir -m 0700  ~/.history` then added

```
[[ -d ~/.history ]] || mkdir --mode=0700 ~/.history
[[ -d ~/.history ]] && chmod 0700 ~/.history
HISTFILE=~/.history/history.$(date +%y%b%d-%H%M%S).$$
# close any old history file by zeroing HISTFILESIZE  
HISTFILESIZE=0  
# then set HISTFILESIZE to a large value
HISTFILESIZE=4096  
HISTSIZE=4096
```

to my `~/.bashrc`. Every now and then, I remember to `du -sk .history` and clean it out. It's nice to have every command I've typed preserved for me.

I just used the above to see what I'd been doing, of late:
`cut -f1 "-d " .history/* | sort | uniq -c |sort -n -r |less`
or
`cut -f1-2 "-d " .history/* | sort | uniq -c |sort -n -r |less`
(to include the 1st argument e.g. `sudo mount` in the sort chain).

Comment: Why do you assign `HISTFILESIZE` twice?

Comment: By setting HISTFILESIZE to 0, I clear the history buffer and reset the history saving mechanism. Then, I set the size I really want, and start saving history in HISTFILE. See the HISTORY section of `man bash`.

Comment: is there a way to merge the history files in order to make `Ctrl+r` work again?

Comment: This should be a new question, but I don't think it's a Good Idea. I use `egrep 'whatever' .history/*` (or `cat .history/* | egrep 'whatever'`) instead, and use Ctrl-r to search an individual session's history. Read `man bash-builtins` about the history command. My `sort .history/* | uniq -c | sort -n | wc -l` shows 16033 unique commands, `cut '-d ' -f1 .history/* | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` shows 2004 unique commands, mostly typos. Loading all that into bash's "history list" would not help.

Comment: @waltinator  - i know this is an old comment, but are you implying that setting an environment variable somehow triggers an immediate action? what process is going to pick up the fact you assigned a value of 0 to HISTFILESIZE in a local shell and then immediately change to 4096? is this something undocumented about bash's handling of certain variable names?

Comment: @Daniel To invoke the Deep Magic.

Comment: @unsynchronized: See `man bash`, the part that starts with`The  following  variables  are  used  by the shell. `

Comment: (+1)  Is it actually necessary to first run `mkdir -m 0700 ~/.history`, then also include it in the second condition in your first line of the code block: `[[ -d ~/.history ]] || mkdir --mode=0700 ~/.history` ? Do the first two lines not ensure (with each new terminal when `.bashrc` is executed) that the folder exists with the expected permissions?

Comment: @n1k31t4 No, not actually necessary, but included for documentation. It's easier to simply set the permission to "what's Right", than to check with `stat -c "%a" ~/.history/` and then fix it if it's wrong. Yes, the two lines ensure that, every time through `~/.bashrc`, my `~/.history` directory exists with the Right permissions.

Answer (score 16):

## History from all shell sessions is less useful than I hoped!

I enthusiastically set `PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -r'` in the hopes that my history usage would be much better!

Wow, was I disappointed.

Essentially, doing this makes up/dn arrow useless.  Because now each history session is littered with commands from other sessions.  And for me this loses the best feature of history.

## What I really wanted

Occasionally, I wanted to essentially transfer my history from one terminal session to another session so I could easily recall commands from that session.  And I can do this very selectively.

## What I did

I set up a series of simple history manipulation aliases & I ignore these commands in the history:

```bsh
alias ha="history -a"
alias hb="history -a; history -r"
alias hr="history -r"
alias hl="history | tail -20"
HISTIGNORE="ha:hb:hr:hl"
```

I think of `hb` as history blend...the others are self-explanatory.

Now when I want to copy my history from session A to session B, I can do this:

- **A:** `ha` - append session **A** history to history file
- **B:** `hb` - append session **B** history to history file and then read the file

This essentially preserves the history order for session **B** and adds session **A** history deeper in the list.

Super useful for me.  Maybe helps you too!

Comment: Use `ctrl+R` to search your history from terminal, that will help with mixed shells...

Comment: This was what I really wanted. Most shells I don't want to keep history, I'm just 'doing stuff', but whenever there's a command I want to use in `ctrl+r` a lot, I can just type `ha` and then new shells will have _that terminals_ history available to `ctrl+r`. To add to live session, `hb` ...  this is my preferred solution.

Answer (score 11):

See also "[keeping persistent history in bash](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/06/11/keeping-persistent-history-in-bash)" for another alternative. It rigs your prompt to send all commands ever typed into *any* terminal into a "persistent history" file (alongside what's usually done for the regular `.history`).

Comment: I inserted **$$** to make the line `echo $$ $date_part "$command_part" >> ~/.persistent_history` This prefixes the entries with the PIDs of their bash process, so that we can disentangle multiple histories.

Comment: Can the alternative history be made to work with CTRL-R history search?

Answer (score 10):

To show `history` from all terminals:

Add `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -r'` to your .bashrc file.

Source: [http://northernmost.org/blog/flush-bash_history-after-each-command](http://northernmost.org/blog/flush-bash_history-after-each-command/)

---

Comment: I will say that after a couple months of using this I eventually commented this out just recently. It is bittersweet as I don't always want to sift through the last 100 commands just to run the one I had originally run in the Tmux pane I sometimes may have a dedicated log command in that I need to restart.

Comment: A nice solution that the fish shell offers is a `history --merge`. I have been using this for a year or so now and it solves the issue. When I want the most recent history from other sessions, I just run that command and it is available to me instantly.

Comment: export is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a more complete solution that persists your bash history locally, stores additional context (cwd, runtime, exit code, etc) and syncs it to your other computers, see [hishtory](https://github.com/ddworken/hishtory). I got frustrated with shell histories misbehaving, and this is my solution to the problem.

Comment: this is awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@brucejo Building on the answer from @waltinator (https://askubuntu.com/a/80882/1679924 ), for Ubuntu i have a small script that i put in my bin folder. Typically i have a few terminals for specific projects, (that i name proj-server, proj-mobile, proj-frontend .. etc) so i can open a gnome-terminal with a {name} and save the history to a file ~/.history/history.{name}

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  export TERMINAL_NAME="default"
else
  export TERMINAL_NAME="$1"
fi

echo "Starting gnome-terminal $TERMINAL_NAME"

HISTDIR="$HOME/.history"

[[ -d "$HISTDIR" ]] || mkdir --mode=700 "$HISTDIR"
[[ -d "$HISTDIR" ]] && chmod 700 "$HISTDIR"
export HISTFILE="$HISTDIR/history.$TERMINAL_NAME"

export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'

echo "Appending history to $HISTFILE"
gnome-terminal -p
```