# How to save live log bash input to a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, logging

When I am teaching a class, some students have problems following my CLI commands and would like to scroll back to be able to repeat the steps in their own speed. So I'd like to log all my inputs in realtime to an html-file or something similar, which I could server through a webserver. That way, the students could simply go to http://example.com/log#end and would always see the last entries.

I do know the multiuser mode of `screen` and have already used it to share sessions. However, I need to disable the write access of students and unfortunately, they are unable to scroll up, if I do so.

I also had a look at `script`, but it generates a terrible output, which - even when filtered through `col -bp < logfile >> output.html` is unreadable. Also, it does log the output as well, which complicates things and only dumps the logfile in unforeseeable intervals.

`.bash_history` could be used, but is only dumped to file when the session ends.

Any ideas?

Comment: This [blog entry](http://www.pointsoftware.ch/en/howto-bash-audit-command-logger/) have a extended description on how it can be done Perhaps the method of this answer could be used http://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals

Comment: wow, very big solution. I might be able to adapt it to my needs and might use it in another scenario as well, thanks. I'll wait for a simpler solution before accepting it, though. ;)

Comment: I use Adobe Captivate when I want to give out instructions.
(You can create some advanced guides, when you learn how to manage the application)

Comment: Do you want ALL keyboard input, or input specifically for bash?  You said bash, but global keygrabbing is easier.  Something to think about.

Comment: Hm, might also be a possibility. In this specific case, I just need bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the built-in command `history`:

```
history -w hist.txt
```

will save the current history into file hist.txt.

If you have write permsiions to the appropriate directory you could do something like:

```
history -w /var/www/html/latest_history.txt
```

Then your students could access it in a browser: http://teachers.ip.address/latest_history.txt

Comment: User @Lars (who has insufficient rep to comment) comments: ----- This is a great answer. I ended up using the following to update it every few seconds `while (true); do history -w /var/www/history.txt sleep 3 done`