# Creating a complete and alphabetically sorted .txt file of bash history

Tags: bash, text-processing, sort, bash-history

I want to have a complete and sorted list of my bash history. But there are some problems:

1. By doing `history` the list never shows the complete list and only 1000 commands are shown.
2. In my **$HOME** directory there is a file named *.bash_history*  that shows 2000 results.
3. When I want to make a sorted *.txt*   file out of my history I do:

   ```
   history | sort > History.txt
   ```

   But because of numbers the commands are not sorted alphabetically and are sorted by number.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: It's not a useful as you might think - see my answer in the comments of https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals/80882#80882

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
cat ~/.bash_history | sort > Sorted_history.txt
```

to have an unlimited bash history, have a look at this QA:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history

Comment: and if you don't want exact repeats, you could "cat ~/.bash_history | sort | uniq  > Sorted_history.txt"

Comment: @jpezz: or more simply `< ~/.bash_history sort -u > Sorted_history.txt`.  And you can use `history -a` first to "append history lines from this session to the history file".

Comment: `history | cut -c 30- | sort -u -i | ack "ssh"` will (for me) cut off the variable parts (time codes and indexing) and then sort. I do get some duplicates, I think because of different whitespace. Pipe it through "ack" as shown to get simple searching.

Answer (score 8):

`sort` can sort input by the field specified by the user to `-k`, so strictly speaking something like this would be what you are looking for.

```
history | sort -k2 > History.txt  # or -K3 if you have $HISTTIMEFORMAT, etc set
```

Additionally, there's often a difference between what's available in the output of `history` command vs what's recorded in `~/.bash_history` in that the latter is not updated after every command (is usually updated only on logout), so using `history | sort ..` is better at giving you a current view.