# Command history seems to be missing the first 75 lines

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, history, bash-history

A couple of years ago, I did the automatic distribution update from 14.04 to 16.04. For the first time in my life, I was able to continue to use the computer after the automatic distribution update. As usual, the software repositories are all muntered, so system updates don't work properly, but I've gotten by.

I am going to do a clean installation of 18.04, however. In order to be able to configure my system more easily after the installation, I exported my command history to a text file.

```
$ history > /.../20180915_Command_history.txt
```

Beautifully, the resulting text file contains line numbers. Somewhat mysteriously, the first line number is 76. After looking at the first few lines, it looks like there were probably some previous commands.

1. Do the line numbers just start at 76 for some reason?
2. If not, is there any way that I can see lines 1 to 75?

Comment: Mine starts from 994 and ends with 1993.

Comment: !-75 is a good command to pull requests

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, If you need to get a backup of your command line history, then just copy this file:

```
~/.bash_history
```

Remember that you have to close all your terminals or run `history -a` to append all commands from those history sessions to the history file.

---

> If not, is there any way that I can see lines 1 to 75?

Every command that has been saved in your history is available at `~/.bash_history` file, to see all of them open a terminal and run:

```
cat ~/.bash_history
```

To get an output similar to `history` command with numbering run:

```
cat -n ~/.bash_history
```

---

> Do the line numbers just start at 76 for some reason?

Run this command:

```
grep "^HIST" .bashrc
```

You have to get an output similar to:

```
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

As I said before `~/.bash_history` keeps command-line's history.

- The `HISTFILESIZE` show how many command should `~/.bash_history` keeps track of, for mine it's 2000.
- And `HISTSIZE` is the number of commands that `history` command (shell built-in actually) keeps track of.

When you open a terminal and run `history`, it will picks the last `HISTSIZE` number of commands from `~/.bash_history` and shows that to you.

If you run new commands it will remove the older ones from session and append the new ones at the end of its list so the number of commands will match `HISTSIZE`.

I guess while asking the question you had 74 command more than of `HISTSIZE` in your `.bash_history` and that's the reason why it starts at 75.

---

From `man bash`:

- `HISTSIZE`

  > The  number of commands to remember in the command history.
- `HISTFILESIZE`

  > The maximum number of lines contained in the history file.

Comment: I'll suggest my per-process `bash` history, see my  answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/80882/25618

Comment: What's the rationale for keeping `HISTSIZE < HISTFILESIZE`? Is there some downside of having `history` lookup *all* available commands? Does it become slow? But then does `1000 vs 2000` really make a difference? I could understand if you had `100k` vs `1000` maybe but I really don't see how that specific setting would achieve anything useful.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I don't think that the number is related to being able to perform the task faster, in my opinion it's for more convenience, I can look into 1000 line of history easier that of 2000. it's like caching data, we keep the most recent one because there is a higher chance that we run them again.

Comment: @Ravexina Yes, but using `Ctrl+R` will show the most recent commands first, so I don't really see any inconvenience in keeping more. You can always do `history | tail -n 1000` to keep just the last 1000 lines so it seems like an unnecessary limitation.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I think it's about being able to have a look into most recent commands really fast not searching about specific result (like using ctrl+r), it's really a pain in the neck to combine `history` with other commands, I prefer running `history` to get my desired output and when I need more then I can just run `tail -2000 ~.bash_history`. It's all about what you prefer if 1000 is not enough for you just increase it... But not to `100K` as you said your self :)