# How can i write only the latest commands to ~/.bash_history file?

Tags: bash, bash-history

my ~/.bash_history file keeps record of all the commands i've typed. can i not put only the latest commands that i've typed from the start of terminal so that it always show me the recently typed commands.

Comment: What OS/release are you using?   You have tagged an EOL/ESM release which is now off-topic for this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1175757/968501

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS