# Save Terminal history

Tags: command-line

I am currently taking a Linux class and working on a project in the command line. I the very last thing I need to do is save all of my work into a log file. The exact phrasing is:
"Create a log file of all the commands you have utilized to this point. Title this file Log_File.txt and download it for submission"
The downnloading part is done through the IDE but I am having a bitch of a time finding the answer to how to make that file that saves everything I did in the project. 
Anything would help.
-Thanks

Comment: Which shell are you using? Most (if not all) shell keep a history of the commands used, reviewing your shell’s manual will tell you which commands to use to obtain them.

Comment: i am using bash? I believe.

Comment: The `script` command will save all screen output (and keyboard input) to a file named *typescript*.

Comment: SInce command history ("`$HISTFILE`" default value `$HOME/.history`) is overwritten when you login again, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals/80882#80882 my answer.

Comment: @waltinator In `bash` the default value of `$HISTFILE` is `~/.bash_history` and its lines are dropped in order to stay inside the `$HISTFILESIZE` limit of by default 2000 lines – why would it be overwritten on login?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you just need to run:

```
history > filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To manage the session history of a `bash` shell there’s the `history` command. Let’s have a look at the relevant parts of `help history`:

> ```
> $ help history
> history: history [-c] [-d offset] [n] or history -anrw [filename] or history -ps arg [arg...]
>     Display or manipulate the history list.
>
>     Display the history list with line numbers, prefixing each modified
>     entry with a `*'.  An argument of N lists only the last N entries.
>
>     Options:
>       -a        append history lines from this session to the history file
>       -w        write the current history to the history file
>
>     If FILENAME is given, it is used as the history file.  Otherwise,
>     if HISTFILE has a value, that is used, else ~/.bash_history.
> ```

When a `bash` shell is started it reads the last (by default 1000) lines from the user’s history file (by default `~/.bash_history`) and builts a session history in the RAM. When you now execute a command line it saves this line to the session history and drops the first line instead – the session history once reached the limit of the 1000 lines doesn’t exceed this limit.

Following this, in order to save only **the session history** i.e. the command lines you executed in this particular terminal window in a file `~/session_history`, it’s:

```
history -a ~/session_history
```

If you however want to save the 1000 lines of history **the session currently holds in memory**, i.e. commands from older sessions and the current one, it’s:

```
history -w ~/session+old_history
```

If you want to save the whole **history of all sessions closed so far**, limited to 2000 lines by default, you just need to copy your default history file:

```
cp ~/.bash_history ~/closed-sessions_history
```

If you want to manually save a session’s history to this file without closing the session, do:

```
history -a
```

If you did that in every open terminal, your history file is up to date with all the command lines you used to this point, copying it now gives you a full **history of closed and open sessions**:

```
cp ~/.bash_history ~/all-sessions_history
```