# Is there an application that can store a list of commands for me to pick and run?

Tags: command-line

I’m finding that I’m starting to build up a long list of regularly used Linux commands and was wondering if there was an application out there that would allow me to store them all, and then pick and run one from the list as and when I need too?

Comment: I'm very confused as to what you are asking. Why are you trying to 'store' commands?

Comment: So I don’t have to type them out,  or scroll through a very long list in the terminal history

Comment: I found something similar to what I’m after, but ideally a bit more polished - https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/124855-bash-menu-script.html

Answer (score 0):

When using `BASH`, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to do a **reverse search** through your command history. For example, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and then type "vim" to see your last command that included "vim".  You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> again to find the second to most recent, and continue pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> until you find the command you want.  Once you find it, you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command.

If you wish to edit the command before running it, you can use the directional (<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd>) which will drop you out of reverse search and allow editing.

To enhance this feature, be sure to allow for many commands to be stored in your `~/.bash_history` file.  You can define the limit by exporting the value of `HISTSIZE` in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export HISTSIZE=10000
```

You can ensure each unique command is only stored once, which is recommended for various reasons including preventing you from having to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> more times than necessary otherwise.  Again add the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

You may also want to adjust the way BASH stores history when multiple terminals are open at once, to ensure commands from multiple terminals are all stored, by [taking a look at this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/80380/13247).

This is one of those most powerful things I've learned on Linux/BASH, and I hope you find it helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `history` command. It is designed to list the commands you have used. You can filter it by using grep:

```
$ history | grep home
```

gives me all the command I used with the word "home" in it, e.g.:

```
 1188  cd ../home
 1519  more resources/home.php 
 1890  cd git/home
 1983  cd git/home
 2001  cd git/home/squeeze/
 2008  history | grep home
```

and this allows me to pick one and re-execute it:

```
$ !2001
```

is equivalent to `cd git/home/squeeze` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to do this. Firstly, there's already a built in  history feature in the shell. Using the `up` and `down` keys allow you to view this as well as `Ctrl r` allowing you search it.

Another option is to make it an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) in `~/.bashrc`.

Thirdly, you could save each command to its on file, and then manually run `bash my_command`.

Comment: How does the third option work exactly, what would need to be in each file, would all files need to be in the same folder etc.?