# append bash history before command finishes

Tags: command-line, bash, history

With the solution in [1] it is possible to write the command to bash_history, after the command has finished, with multiple terminals.

That means, if the command is issued and if something happens during the time the command runs, it is not appended to history.

Is it possible to append a command to bash_history immediately after hitting enter before the command finishes?

[1] [Bash history handling with multiple terminals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals)

Comment: Run the same command in a `DEBUG` trap

Comment: @muru: how can I automate this? It should be all commands automatically, how do I need to edit bashrc?