# How to merge history from multiple terminal session

Tags: history, fish

Is there a way to merge history from multiple terminal sessions in Fish shell?

I tried to use the command `history merge` but I get the following error"

> history: you cannot use any options with the merge command

Has anyone been able to do this in Fish Shell?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals will probably also work for the fish shell.

Comment: If `history merge` is thinking that you are using additional options (when you aren't), I wonder if you have an alias (or other function) masking `history`.  Can you double-check `type -s history`?  It should point to `/usr/share/fish/functions/history.fish`.  If we're on the right track, then I can convert this into an answer.  Otherwise, we'll keep noodling on it :-)

Comment: And to answer the last part of your question, `history merge` works for me.  Can you confirm your Fish shell version?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'm using version 3.3.1

Comment: @Oren Did you get a chance to try the `type -s history` from my previous comment?  I see that the error you are receiving was a recent addition to Fish, so I just upgraded one of my test VMs, but I still don't have the same problem.  `history merge` returns without error for me on 3.3.1.

Comment: When i type 'history is a function (defined in -)' I get: history is a function (defined in -)
I get the history merge error on my Kubuntu laptop and my work laptop using WSL 2
What do you think? Should I open an issue on Fish Shell Github account?