# How can I sync all terminal sessions to one history file?

Tags: bash, command-line

when I open terminal session A, type some commands , and then type "history" I see the commands that I was running, but then if I open another terminal session (B) and type "history" I don't see the commands that were typed in to the session A terminal.

how can I sync the history of all terminal sessions in to one file, so when I type "history" from one terminal session I will se the commands from all the sessions?

Comment: Probably by using some sort of PROMPT_COMMAND shenanigan and writing the commands to a textfile, then tailing that textfile when you type history
Turns out there was another real solution, see below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash history handling with multiple terminals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals)

Answer (score 1):

adding

`shopt -s histappend` and `PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'`

to your .bashrc file should make your terminals append rather than overwrite the `.bash_history` file.

Then the history command would probably reflect whatever was typed last regardless of terminal.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. Bash version: 5.1.8.

Comment: Indeed it does not work for me either as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

i found something that works perfectly,
added the following line to .bashrc file.

export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"