# Is there a way to regularly backup terminal history to a textfile?

Tags: 20.04, bash, backup, bash-history

Since the bash_history file saves only the last n commands, I'd like to create a file that has the entire history of all the commands ever entered in the system.

```
history > textfile.txt
```

saves the last 1000 commands to a text file. Is there a way to regularly and automatically back up the terminal history to a text file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash history handling with multiple terminals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals)

Answer (score 1):

I have a better option, [Atuin](https://github.com/atuinsh/atuin), which stores your shell history in a SQLite database. You can still use the up arrow and CTRL+R to search your shell history, though.

In addition, Atuin enables synchronised history across multiple computers. So for example, I have a laptop, desktop and server, all with one shared history of commands.

It's pretty awesome. Here's what it looks like when I press CTRL+R. I get a pretty interface to my past history.

[image: Atuin]

The sync happens via a server. You can either use the Atuin server, where your commands are encrypted (so they can't see them), or you can run your own Atuin server.